# When a link is clicked, make another link active- angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a sidebar with these elements :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
      <li class="nav-item collapsed side" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home" >
          <a class="nav-link"  routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home </a> </li>
     <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="home">

          <li class="nav-item list-unstyled"><a class="nav-link"  routerLinkActive="active"  routerLink="/home/submenu1">Submenu1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item list-unstyled"><a class="nav-link"   routerLinkActive="active"  routerLink="/home/submenu2">Submenu2</a></li>

      </ul>


      <li class="nav-item side">
          <a class="nav-link"  routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
      </li>

  </ul>
```

When clicking on Submenu1 , I want Home to be set to active so that it takes the css that I've applied for when a link is active.
How do I do this in Angular5 ?
Thank you.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngClass` and in your component have code to check if the route is part of the home route. For example:

```
let isHomeActive = Router.url.startsWith("/home/");
this.homeClasses = {
    "active": isHomeActive,
    "nav-link": true
}

<a [ngClass]="homeClasses"  routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home </a> </li>
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much!
One question though, on the constructor I imported Router ` private router:Router`. 
And when I write the let isHomeActive... code on it, on the this.homeClasses I get property does not exist in AppComponent